# 3.5 month old wakes up from nap after 30 mins and will only go back to sleep by feeding

Tags: sleep, bottle-feeding

My little guy has never been a great sleeper but we hand him on a pretty rough schedule up until last week. He had to go to the hospital for 3 days. He is well now but his naps are completely off. He is easy to get down, probably because I feed him to sleep (another problem I want to work on) but he has been waking up at EVERY nap after 30 mins. I try letting him cry for a few minutes (never works) going in and patting him, giving him his pacifier, sometimes I pick him up, nothing works. I finally give him a bottle and that sometimes gets him back to sleep. I have to feed him for about 10 mins and try to quickly switch out his paci for his bottle but he usually wakes up and I have to start the feeding process over again. Most days I just give up and end the "nap" by getting him up for a real feeding.

1. How do get him not to wake up after only 30 mins?
2. How do I get him to go back to sleep with out feeding him? He sleeps pretty well at night. We put him down around 8, wakes up at 3, asleep again until 6 so I know he is capable of going back to sleep on his own. We swaddle at naps and bedtime and his room is dark.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Could it be that he's just waking up because he's hungry, and you need to feed him more/earlier before putting him down to sleep?  Possibly related: [How can I keep my infant from sleeping while bottle feeding](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/how-can-i-keep-my-infant-from-sleeping-while-bottle-feeding?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that he just doesn't want to sleep anymore?  If he has "naps", I imagine it is more than one and half an hour each time sounds already good enough for me.  If he sleeps well at night, if he is happy and you too when he wakes up after his nap, why would you want to put him back to bed?

And also:  there is no problem with feeding your baby to sleep (unless you leave him sleeping with the bottle of milk for instance). Everything that works and makes you and baby happy, take it. :)